# How do I set up IntelliJ to build Haskell projects with Stack?

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, haskell-stack

I am using Stack to setup, build, and run my Haskell projects from the command line. I want to use IntelliJ as my IDE but am running into problems configuring Stack as my build tool.

I used Stack to create and run a "Hello, World" Haskell program on the command line following the instructions in the Stack [User Guide](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/). Everything worked fine.

I have the HaskForce plugin installed on IntelliJ. The Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Haskell Compiler tab gives you a choice between building with Stack and building with Cabal. I selecte Build with stack and configured it like so.

[image]

I can run the project using a Haskell Stack Run configuration. The console output is correct.

```
/Users/williammcneill/Library/Haskell/bin/stack exec hellohaskell-exe --
Hello, Haskell.
```

However, I cannot figure out how to rebuild the project through the IDE. For example, if I change the output text and rerun the program, I still see the original "Hello, Haskell" output. Build -> Make Project | Make Module | Rebuild Project all do nothing.

The Project Settings->Artifacts tab has nothing listed, and I don't see a way to add a Haskell executable here.

My workaround is to build my Haskell programs from the command line even when I'm editing from the IDE.

(It also looks strange to me to specify a path to a project-specific `stack.yaml` file in the general Haskell compiler settings, but that was the only way I could see how to use Stack to build.)

How do I set up IntelliJ to build Haskell projects using Stack?

*ghc 7.10.3, stack 1.1.2, HaskForce 0.3-beta.33, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1.3, OS X 10.11.5*

---

This is Haskforce [issue 282](https://github.com/carymrobbins/intellij-haskforce/issues/282).

Comment: This might help you, 
https://gist.github.com/androidfred/a2bef54310c847f263343c529d32acd8

Answer (score 17):

If you want to hit the IntelliJ run button to run the project and use Stack, I think you should use the [IntelliJ Haskell Plugin](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell) as @mrek said.
The [HaskForce plugin](https://github.com/carymrobbins/intellij-haskforce) says at the moment

> Note: Run configurations are not supported for stack at the moment. This is for cabal projects only.

The install instructions for everything (from installing Stack to project setup) are in the [readme](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell#getting-started), but I needed to change it slightly so I put my version here.

**Installation instructions for everyone who wants to use Haskell**

1. Install the IntelliJ-Haskell plugin, I would recommend to install the latest beta release from [GitHub](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell/releases).
2. Install Stack, instructions in [their docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/) (scroll down for your specific OS).
3. In a terminal/command prompt, run `stack install hindent` and `stack install stylish-haskell` (this can take a while).
4. Restart your computer.
5. Make a new project in IntelliJ of type Haskell module, select the Stack binary (probably `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\stack.exe` or `/usr/bin/stack`) and Set Default (if it is not already default).

   - You can also import an existing Stack project with File | New | Project from Existing Sources, click import from Haskell Stack.
6. Switch on an extra log with File | Settings | Appearance | Notifications | Haskell Log. When something is building which takes a long time you can see progress here (bottom right, Event Log).
7. You should have a file `app/Main.hs`. You could replace everything in it with `main = putStrLn "Hello Haskell!"`.
8. Now do as @mrek says: create a run configuration Haskell Stack | Haskell Stack Runner, and run it. You should see the hello message.
9. Even better, answering the original question: when you change the message and run again the output has changed!
10. In the same way, you can make a test run configuration (Haskell Stack Tester) which runs your tests.

You can start up the interactive console by clicking Terminal at the bottom of IntelliJ and then running `stack ghci`. When you type `main` you are calling main, and so on.
You could also use `stack test` instead of the test run configuration.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you have [IntelliJ Haskell plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8258-intellij-haskell) installed.

1. Go to *Run -> Edit Configurations -> Haskell Stack -> Haskell Stack Runner*:

[image]

2. Set the name of the configuration. Executable file name should be added automatically. Then press OK.

[image]

Now, you should be able to build the project.

Output:

`/usr/local/bin/stack build --exec test-project-exe
It works!`